# JUnit 5 @ParameterizedTest with using class as @ValueSource

Tags: java, junit5, parameterized

I want to do a `ParameterizedTest` with `@ValueSource` , i have readed many tutorials including [Guide to JUnit 5 Parameterized Tests](https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5):

```
/**
 * The {@link Class} values to use as sources of arguments; must not be empty.
 *
 * @since 5.1
 */
Class<?>[] classes() default {};
```

So i tried the following :

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(classes = {new Mandator("0052", "123456", 79)})
void testCalculateMandateI(Mandator value) {

     //code using Mandator here
}
```

Mandator class:

```
 public class Mandator {

    private String creditorPrefix;
    private String retailerCode;
    private int mandateIdSequence;

    public Mandator(final String creditorPrefix, final String retailerCode, final int mandateIdSequence) {
        this.creditorPrefix = creditorPrefix;
        this.retailerCode = retailerCode;
        this.mandateIdSequence = mandateIdSequence;
    }

    public String getCreditorPrefix() {
        return creditorPrefix;
    }

    public String getRetailerCode() {
        return retailerCode;
    }

    public int getMandateIdSequence() {
        return mandateIdSequence;
    }
}
```

---

But i get the following error from IntelliJ , hovering above @ValueSource :

[image]

**Attribute value must be a constant**

What am i doing wrong here ? What am i missing ?

Comment: The first one explains how to use JUnit with sources. The others explain the cause of the error, "Attribute value must be a constant", you received. They're all relevant.

Comment: if you ever need test against class definition
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(classes = {ClassA.class, ClassB.class, ClassC.class})
void classTest(Class<?> clazz) {
assertThat( /* Logic related with class check */).isTrue();
 }

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Its not about JUnit but about Java Syntax.

Its impossible to create new objects in parameters of the annotations.

The type of an annotation element is one of the following:

- List A primitive type (int, short, long, byte, char, double, float, or boolean)
- String
- Class (with an optional type parameter such as Class)
- An enum type
- An annotation type
- An array of the preceding types (an array of arrays is not a legal element type)

If you want to supply values out of created objects consider using something like this as one possible solution:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("generator")
void testCalculateMandateI(Mandator value, boolean expected)

// and then somewhere in this test class  
private static Stream<Arguments> generator() {

 return Stream.of(
   Arguments.of(new Mandator(..), true),
   Arguments.of(new Mandator(..), false));
}
```

Comment: Excellent , i just don't understand what is that `true`, `false` you have added on `Arguments.of()`

Comment: It should be an expected result. After all given different parameters you expect different results to be verified. It doesn't have to be a boolean though, only something that you will be able to verify upon.